# Redirecting STDERR on login

Tags: linux, bash, app-startup

I have a menu system that all users are automatically directed to. This is done by changing the shell attribute in /etc/passwd to point to a script that sources the profile and generally sets up the environment before calling the main program.

For example, a store manager would be like this:

`strmgr:x:1234:1234:Store Manager:/home/storeuser:/opt/menu/start_menu.sh`

I'm looking for a way to capture **STDERR** from the login process to a file that I can then interrogate in the menu script itself, displaying the important pieces as needed.

My initial thought was to add `exec &2>/tmp/$$.stderr`
at the top of the script but that doesn't work as I'd hoped. There are still system generated messages that are masked by the menu display. I guess they're generated before this script is called, even though I'm not using the "normal" shell and .profile start-up.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?  I've scoured google and found nothing.

Comment: While the anser provided by Gilles Quenot should work, I personally would not place **any** logic into configuration files such as `passwd` or `crontab` etc. Instead, I would write a simple wrapper around start_menu.sh, which just calls start_menu.sh with stderr redirected. Maybe one day you want to do more setup work (perhaps turn on tracing with `-x` for debugging), and if you have everything in your wrapper script, it is easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
exec 2>/tmp/$$.stderr
```

The `&` is a shorthand for `2>&1` (redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  There are still messages that are being generated before the start_menu script is run apparently.

Comment: I was hoping that the start_menu script would  supplant the shell but I guess when it is called a default shell is opened.  Our security layer (CA's ControlMinder) is automagically called before the script starts and those are the messages I'm missing.

Plan B is to check ControlMinder internal to the script.  It doubles the work but gets the job done...